# Performance Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e testando algumas chamadas `ajax` me deparei com duas situações diferentes, mas que, em ambas, tenho o retorno que preciso.

O que quero saber é, se existe alguma forma mais indicada, e qual a diferença entre elas, se alguma é mais rápida, etc...

## Situação Primeira

**Javascript**

```
// ajax
get_ajax(1, true);
function get_ajax(id, aguardar) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: !aguardar,
        data: { id: id },
        url: 'controller/get_ajax',
        success: (...)
        error:(...)
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
// controller
public function get_ajax()
{
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    print_r($id);
}
```

## Situação Segunda

**Javascript**

```
// ajax
get_ajax(1, true);
function get_ajax(id, aguardar) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: !aguardar,        
        url: 'controller/get_ajax/' + id,
        success: (...)
        error:(...)
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
// controller
public function get_ajax($id)
{
    print_r($id);
}
```

Aparentemente são iguais, exceto a forma como o argumento `id` está sendo passado.

Na `primeira situação`, estou enviando o `id` através de `data:` e recuperando no controller através do método `GET`.

Na `segunda situação`, estou enviando o `id` através da `URL` do `ajax`, e recuperando através do parâmetro.

Comment: Não há diferença significativa quanto à performance, principalmente quando usa o `jQuery`.

Comment: E não use `async:false`

Comment: Por qual motivo não usar false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas formas estão corretas, o resultado vai ser o mesmo e acredito que não vá ter uma diferença de desempenho considerável.

Eu usaria a primeira situação só por achar mais organizado.